# Why is the printing order reversed in a simple loop built inside a function(Python)

Tags: python, string, function, loops, split

I have a simple function inside which i run a loop and then perform split operation on the extracted string element. Once operation is done on the current element i am printing the 2nd splitted text of the complete string and then moving to next element of the list.

However, when the function is called, i find the output printed in reverse order i.e. from the last element of list to first.

Here is the code:

```
s={"i am good", " i am fine"}
def splitter():
    for i in s:
        print(i.split()[2])
splitter()
```

**Output:**

```
fine
good
```

However, expected output is:

```
good
fine
```

Comment: `s` is a `set`, a `set` does not maintain the order that items were inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sets are not ordered in python, you can use list instead

```
s = ["i am good", " i am fine"]
def splitter():
    for i in s:
        print(i.split()[2])
splitter()
```